# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' even though mysqld is running on port 3306

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-connector-python

Trying to connect to mysql through python using mysql-connector, but I am getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_stf_file_names.py", line 26, in update_aws_script_details
    database="service_portal"
  File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "/var/www/html/cloudlab/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection refused)
```

I have checked if port 3306 is being used by mysqld and it is:

```
netstat -lnp | grep 3306
```

which gave:

```
tcp        0      0 my-ip:3306      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12003/mysqld
```

I also tried this command and it works perfectly:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

(As in I can connect to the database using this)

I am trying to access the database in the following way:

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="****",
    passwd="****",
    database="**********"
    )
    cursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

If I change localhost in the above command to my-ip, then it works fine. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you can not reach 3306 with ip, can you try windows firewall>advance settings > inbound rule create new rule to acces your ip to 3306 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost it's an ip 127.0.0.1.
Is your mysql instance listening on that exactly ip or on an external one?

Comment: my-ip is not 127.0.0.1. it is an external ip. so... this is the problem then?

Comment: @GaneshBiradar I _guess_ whether `mysql` is listening on a network interface rather than `lo`? Or the config file has denied localhost to connect?

Comment: my-ip falls in the range of 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255. so does this mean that the interface is not localhost? if yes, is there any way i can make it listen on both the localhost and the exisiting my-ip?

Comment: I think you have allies at resolv.conf to your external ip from localhost. Try to define external ip explicitly in your code

Comment: @Alex_H as I have already mentioned in my question, if i give define the ip instead of localhost, it works. Could you please tell if there is way to make it work with localhost also?

Comment: So I checked the contents of resolve.conf:```root@ubuntuhost229:/usr/lib/cgi-bin# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.140.50.5
```

Comment: @GaneshBiradar ```bind-address=127.0.0.1``` at my.cnf. Restart an instance after that change

Comment: Okay, will do that. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Even i faced the same error while installing .So if you have already installed it ,first uninstall it and delete the folder   C:\ProgramData\MySQL   .
Once that is done download the file and install it .

Note: while installing change the port number to 3307 or 3308 and install it normally by following some youtube video .The only change should be the port number 3306⚠️(shows the port is already in use) to 3307 or 3308 or anything else.
wherever ⚠️ appears change the directory or the port number .

Finally while launching the new database through mysqlworkbench change the port to 3307 or 3308 as you have done while installing .

if connection already exist as root right click and press edit the connection and change port to 3307 and press test connection.It will work .
If you face any error please reply back

Answer (score 0):

[image: Mysql Installer]

Reconfiguring the mysql server using the mysql installer works for me

[Source](https://sebhastian.com/fix-cant-connect-mysql-server-localhost-10061/)